# Narrowing second parameter type based on first union parameter in an overloaded function

Tags: typescript, overloading, type-narrowing

I overloaded a function to encode a URI based on it's type. But `params` type is not narrowed inside function body and generates error.
(In real life `params` are interfaces)

```js
export function UriEncode(uriType: 'ExternalS3', params: number): string;
export function UriEncode(uriType: 'LocalS3', params: string): string;
export function UriEncode(uriType: UriType, params: unknown): string {
  if (uriType === 'LocalS3') {
    return params;
    //     ^---Error: Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'
  }
  return 'something';
}
```

How can I have `params` type?
Maybe using Generics instead of overloading?

Thanks for your time...

Comment: There are several previous versions of this question, but I don't have a link to one with a really satisfactory answer... I assume there is one, I just don't have the link.

Comment: Tobias S. found the link. But just FWIW since it's tailored to your question, here's the answer I'd written when I couldn't find one: https://pastebin.com/vLK8ZNhP